# How to send data to Code behind in Dojo

Tags: asp.net, dojo

Just today morning I started to work with dojo with NO support. Hence, feeling everything difficuilt.

I have one form with Fields: DeptNo, DName, Loc.

User can enter either nothing or all the values for the above fields and clicks on Search button.

Now, I should able to read these values in code behind to make service call.

Since I am using just HTML input elements I am not understanding how to pass these values into Code behind.

Can anybody please suggest me on this.

Comment: Are you talking about the  Dojo Toolkit?  Maybe this will help: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/start/

Comment: There are some good tutorials which have good example of dojo forms, TextBox and to get data from forms as suggested by @Tim Please follow dojotoolkit tutorials.